# Get first item in array and push it in a new one

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a Ranking plugin for a Fishing championship; I need to create two rankings, one rank is based on the Fishing Area (sector) and the other rank is general.

I got this structure

Sector 1

```
[0]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(1)
    ["sector"]=> string "B"
    ["score"]=> int(100) 
} 
[1]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(2)
    ["sector"]=> string "B"
    ["score"]=> int(95)
}
```

Sector 2

```
[0]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(3)
    ["sector"]=> string "C"
    ["score"]=> int(96)
} 
[1]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(4)
    ["sector"]=> string "C"
    ["score"]=> int(90)   } }
```

My aim is to get all the first places for each sector and order them descending, then all the second places, then all the third, etc... so in the end I'll have an unique array like so

```
[0]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(1)
    ["sector"]=> string "B"
    ["score"]=> int(100)
} 
[1]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(3)
    ["sector"]=> string "C"
    ["score"]=> int(96)
}
[2]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(2)
    ["sector"]=> string "B"
    ["score"]=> int(95)
} 
[3]=> object(WP_Post)#6197 (24) {
    ["ID"]=> int(4)
    ["sector"]=> string "C"
    ["score"]=> int(90)
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks a lot

Tried with array_map(), array_unshift() but with no luck.

Comment: It would seem more logical to do the sorting as part of the fetching from the database